# Deshacer commits pendientes con GIT

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

estoy usando GIT en un proyecto realice un commit por error y quiero deshacerlo ¿Qué comando tengo que usar?
Gracias!

Comment: Ya hiciste push o solo el commit? Deseas desaparecerlo del historial o te basta con crear un commit que revierta los cambios?

Comment: ¿Es el último commit? Por favor, agrega más detalles a tu pregunta.

Comment: Solo hice el commit y si, es el ultimo commit claro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si no has echo el push y quieres volver antes de hacer el commit sin anular los últimos cambios realizados utiliza este comando:

```
git reset --soft HEAD~1
```

Si no quieres los últimos cambios sustituye --soft por --hard

```
git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

Reset hace que retroceda a HEAD-1 que es la versión anterior a la que estabas.

Comment: Es decir yo después del commit he realizado cambios en la rama (no en los archivos commiteados en otros) y realizado algún pull que tampoco a afectado a lso archivos commiteados simplemente quiero sacar esos archivos del commit y seguir trabajando. ¿debería usar el  git reset en este caso?

Comment: git rm 'archivo' con esto borras los archivos de más que ya no quieras y con
git rm -r 'carpeta' borras la carpeta si la has creado porque lo demás no no has modificado pero realmente al decir que has echo varios push no se si lo que quieres es revertir tus commit o eliminar archivos que no te son útiles.